# How does the environment shape taste in alternate worlds

Tags: evolution, alternate-worlds

We all know there are factors leading to the various ways of flight, walking, running, crawling, climbing and swimming. Those factors are independet  of the creature as those are motions and motion is an adaptation to environment.

The environment shapes life.

Thus those factors are simulated and can work for both real and imaginary creatures.
Hence why there are plenty of artists passionate about evolution building entire worlds with diverse realistic and science proof biologies as a mental sport activity.

I need to know how would various environments shape not the motion of an animal, but it's ability to perceive taste in food.

If taste is indeed shaped by the environment and is not in fact just a random evolutionary event with no meaning, afterall there are no lead sweetened roman wines in the jungle, but they were famous for their taste anyway.

Comment: This seems to be a question about actual evolution, not worldbuilding. Perhaps you can clarify your question in a context appropriate for this site.

Comment: @Mathaddict not enough? "Hence why there are plenty of artists passionate about evolution building entire worlds with diverse realistic and science proof biologies as a mental sport activity.”

Comment: What is the actual worldbuilding question here? there are many things that effect taste beside the environment, the taste preference a koala, snake, and tree frog are going to be vastly different despite living in the same place.

Comment: "Environmental niche", (ie. dietary requirements) rather than environment as such I'd say was the key factor to consider.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking about evolution, the first question is, always, why did evolution develop this?
In the case of taste, I presume that this is for two reasons:

1. We can identify quite a few poisonous substances because they "taste bad". Evolutionary, the ability to taste, and disgust for "bad taste" probably saved a few individuals from poisoning.
2. The human body requires several different nutrients. Turns out: when you eat lots of things that taste differently, you have a good chance to get all those nutrients. The ability to taste, and the fact that most people find it boring to eat things that taste the same all the time, might be evolutionary drive to get a varied diet.

So, what does this mean for your world? I would ask myself two questions:

1. Which substances are dangerous for the animals there?
2. Which substances do they require?

Those are the things they can identify, based on taste.

The question how those things taste for them is impossible to answer. After all, we cannot describe a taste that we, as humans, can not perceive. This is like answering the question what ultra-violet light looks like. The best we can do: Poisonous things taste bad, things that they need taste good.

Keep in mind that this may be disproportionate: As humans, we like sugar. And in fact, we require some sugar. But then, too much sugar is bad. One could say, we like sugar more than is good for us. The reason is, likely, that sugar was seldom when our species evolved, and so we did not get too much even if we ate all the sugar we could get our hands on.